# How long brute force AES-128 at 24 bits of key

Tags: aes, brute-force-attack

I have 1 block of encrypted data with AES-128, but I know 104 bits of 128 bits the key.

How long it will take to brute force 24 bits of a key at Intel I 7 CPU? How can I calculate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz`. Intel I7 has around [10 generations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i7_microprocessors#Comet_Lake_microarchitecture_(10th_generation)) to speak of. The result cannot be accurate without providing the actual referenced Intel I7.

Here is the method;

Run `openssl speed -evp aes-128-cbc` command. That will give you the metric.

My CPUs output:

`aes-128-cbc for 3s on 16 size blocks: 144516288 aes-128-cbc's in 3.00s`,

that is $144516288 = 2^{27.1066568628459}$. Therefore 1 seconds is more than enough.

\begin{array}{|c|r|r|} \hline
2^i & \text{seconds} & \text{years} \\ \hline
2^{30} & 22.29 & 0.0000007\\ \hline
2^{40} & 22824.65 & 0.0007\\ \hline
2^{50} & 23372450.03 & 0.74\\ \hline
2^{60} & 23933388835.87 & 758.92\\ \hline
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
2^{128} & 7.06388957874987e30 & 2.23994469138441e23\\ \hline
\end{array}

The below code ( tested in SageMath )

```
SecondsInADay = 86400
SecondsInAYear = 31536000
TotalCBCin3Sec = 144516288 #your CPU time from openssl speed -evp aes-128-cbc
power = (30,40,50,60,128)

for i in power:
    print('seconds for 2^{%d} =' % (i),end="")
    print(((2^i *3.0)/TotalCBCin3Sec).str(no_sci=2))
for i in power:
    print('years for 2^{%d}   =' % (i),end="")
    print(((2^i *3.0)/TotalCBCin3Sec/SecondsInAYear).str(no_sci=2))
```

Comment: 2^28.10665=289,031,201 not 144,516,288 that mean to run at 50bits 2^50/(144516288/3)=23,372,450 around seconds in your CPU?

Comment: @Bruteforce my mistake, I've added 1, corrected. Yes, the ratio is correct. That is around 270 days

Comment: technically that benchmark is for block encryption not key expansion + block encryption, but the key schedule for AES is VERY fast with hardware acceleration

Comment: @RichieFrame that is completely true. Actually, one needs to write a code to see the actual power. I didn't use this since even the runs of OpenSSL vary. Maybe in little later I need to implement. Thanks.